# how can I normalize n different set of data using a provided method which can only normalize a set of data

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, deep-learning

I have n set of changing data, and I want to normalize every set of data using the [running mean method](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/43159/how-to-calculate-pooled-variance-of-two-groups-given-known-group-variances-mean), since every set has its own mean and std, I have to keep n different module to help me compute it. I do not know how can I maintain n different `Scaler`, I have just been told that I can not import it multiple times and rename it to get different ones. But I do not know how to do this.

If needed, my running mean method `Scaler` is listed as follows,

```
class Scaler(object):
""" Generate scale and offset based on running mean and stddev along axis=0

    offset = running mean
    scale = 1 / (stddev + 0.1) / 3 (i.e. 3x stddev = +/- 1.0)
"""

def __init__(self, obs_dim):
    """
    Args:
        obs_dim: dimension of axis=1
    """
    self.vars = np.zeros(obs_dim)
    self.means = np.zeros(obs_dim)
    self.m = 0
    self.n = 0
    self.first_pass = True

def update(self, x):
    """ Update running mean and variance (this is an exact method)
    Args:
        x: NumPy array, shape = (N, obs_dim)
    """
    if self.first_pass:
        self.means = np.mean(x, axis=0)
        self.vars = np.var(x, axis=0)
        self.m = x.shape[0]
        self.first_pass = False
    else:
        n = x.shape[0]
        new_data_var = np.var(x, axis=0)
        new_data_mean = np.mean(x, axis=0)
        new_data_mean_sq = np.square(new_data_mean)
        new_means = ((self.means * self.m) + (new_data_mean * n)) / (self.m + n)
        self.vars = (((self.m * (self.vars + np.square(self.means))) +
                      (n * (new_data_var + new_data_mean_sq))) / (self.m + n) -
                     np.square(new_means))
        self.vars = np.maximum(0.0, self.vars)  # occasionally goes negative, clip
        self.means = new_means
        self.m += n

def get(self):
    """ returns 2-tuple: (scale, offset) """
    return 1/(np.sqrt(self.vars) + 0.1)/3, self.means
```

Thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an array of Scalar instances. If you have different `obs_dim` for each dataset, you can do `[Scalar(obs_dim) for obs_dim in obs_dims]`. If you have one `obs_dim`, use `[Scalar(obs_dim) for i in range(N)]` where `N` is the number of datasets. You can then refer to each of these by index in the array.